# How to set Maven dependencies on a local jar file

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I am starting to play around with Maven, to see whether we could use it in the future to handle our dependency management, and IDE environments.

I have looked at some YouTube vids on how to get started with Eclipse (we also use Eclipse), and where you basically start off with creating a new project of type Maven. I have done this, and imported my existing source into the src/main package type.

Now I want to start adding the dependencies. No changes to my pom file yet.

I have two directories with jar files in them, and I need to set those dependencies in the pom file. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you usually use Maven. You can add a jar through a path

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.javap.web</groupId>
   <artifactId>testRunWrapper</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/testRunWrapper.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

but the recommended way is to draw your jars from a Maven repository (like MavenCentral, or your Nexus/Artifactory).

So if you want to use Maven in your company, make sure you have a running Nexus or Artifactory server in your company as well. Then you can either proxy external Maven repositories (which contain most of the available open source components) or upload your own jars through the interface of your Nexus/Artifactory.

Comment: Thank you for the tips - I did not know about the Maven repository. Looks like I have some reading to do then...